# Why is my program throwing NameError: name 'x' is not defined for line norm(x)?

Tags: python-3.x, nameerror

On the line inside my main() function, I am getting a name error when I call function norm(x). This is the only function I am having an issue with in this whole program.

```
def read_fp_numbers():
    x = input('Please enter several floating point numbers separated 
by spaces. ').split(' ')
    x = [float(i) for i in x]
    return(x)
def norm(x):
    x = (sum(x))**(.5)
    x = str(x)
    return(x)
def display_norm(x):
    print('norm =', x)
    return(x)
def main():
    read_fp_numbers()
    norm(x)
    display_norm(x)
main()
```

Comment: In the context of `main():`, `x` is indeed not defined. The other `x`s are local to their functions.

Comment: The variables created in the functions only exist in them, therefore x only exists where you defined it, I recommend you read a basic tutorial.

Comment: You should store fp_numbers (E.G. `x = read_fp_numbers()`)

Answer (score 1):

You never captured the returned values

```
def main():
    x= read_fp_numbers()
    display_norm(norm(x))
```